# How to set id to a form_for in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form_for in my `Communication` page i.e below:

```
<%= form_for (:Communication) do |f| %>
```

And I want to add and id of form_for Like below:

```
<%= form_for :Communication, :html => {:id => "communication_form"} do |f| %>
```

But its not working means when I getting `form_for` id in the javascript like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#communication_form").submit(function() {
      alert("Hassan");
   });
</script>
```

And in the jquery i am using `alert("Hassan")` for showing message on the screen, But its not showing any message on the screen means its not going into jquery code using id of the form, Kindly suggest me where I make mistake to assign an id to `Form_for`, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: check your form id in the fire bug.

Comment: You should check you head tag and see whether you have jquery included in there or not, inspect your view and you should also see your browser console tab to see is there any error mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

You did not add your code inside a document ready handler, so you are trying to access `#communication_form` before it exists in the DOM. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#communication_form").submit(function() {
            alert("Hassan");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its not wrking, and also this `$(function()` not necessary when using this `$("#communication_form").submit(function()`.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan this is not the case..... even without using document ready handler submit event would respond. He surely is missing jquery.js or ui js files.

Comment: @user3497277 @alok It is required, otherwise the `submit` event will not be attached at all.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not required, I have done it many a times and before writing previous comment I have cross-checked it with a sample app/page.

Comment: @Alok if you're placing your script at the bottom of your page you are correct. If in the head, you are not.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this I agree with, sorry I did not mention this. I guess OP has issues with inclusion of js files, so his code is not working.